# How to use progress bar when background is busy

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I want to set a progress bar for my application.

I am using a background to download somefiles from my server.

It would be nice if I set a progress bar for that.

I know to use

```
ProgressBar.Value = 5;
```

and more.

but I want to use progress bar.'

I am using this code for progress bar

```
private void bgDownload_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.downloadProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

but its not working.

Can any one say how can I do it.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing processing in the background, the UI will not update until its over.

So what you'll need to do is create a seperate thread which the processing will happen in, and within that thread update the progress bar. In the main thread don't do anything.

To update the progress bar from within another thread, you will need a delegate (or you'll get a runtime error).

Hope this can get you started.

Comment: can u please provide me somecode because i dont know progress bar i have just seen it

Comment: This is incorrect.  If he is doing this in the background (different thread) then the UI will update as long as a value is passed to the UI using a BeginInvoke or the BackGroundWorker Progress Changed Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use **BackgroundWorker** to download some files.

So backgroud download won't effect your Process Bar.

```
    private void btnDownLoad_Click(System.Object sender, 
        System.EventArgs e)
    {

        // Start the asynchronous operation.
        backgroundWorkerDownLoadFile.RunWorkerAsync();
    }



    private void backgroundWorkerDownLoadFile_DoWork(object sender, 
        DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        // Get the File in Server.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using background worker component. So, you will have to call `ReportProgress` method of backgroundworker from its `DoWork` method which should update the progress bar. Please find below some reference on ReportProgress method from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

in addition to what JKhuang wrote, to alter the values in your progress bar you'll need to add
a delegate and a callback function

```
delegate void SetProgCallback(int newVal);
private void SetProgressbarValue(int newVal)
{
    if (progbar.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetProgCallback d = SetProgressbarValue;
        Invoke(d, new object[] { newVal });
    }
    else
    {
        //insert your actual code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could use an Action<> instead of a delegate. progbar.Invoke(new Action<int>(SetProgressbarValue, new object[] { newVal }));

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do this.

```
    public int ProgressBarPercentage { get; set; }
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public void StartDownload()
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Run clean up code here once complete (ie make sure progress bar is at 100 percent....
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Download files here
        List<string> filestoget = new List<string>();
        filestoget.Add("File1");
        filestoget.Add("File2");
        filestoget.Add("File3");
        filestoget.Add("File4");
        filestoget.Add("File5");

        foreach (string file in filestoget)
        {
            // Get File

            // Report output
            int progress = 0; // add soemthing here to calculate your progress
            bw.ReportProgress(progress, string.Format("File {0} downloaded", file));
        }
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressBarPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
        StatusMessage = e.UserState.ToString();
    }
```